# save mathod in database cause Array to string conversion error in laravel

Tags: database, laravel

when I execute custom command with

```
php artisan query:all
```

every thing is good except error shown in console the error is

> Array to string conversion

and the data is stored to database I did not understand the cause of this error and it's hidden when hide save to database method
the code of my service which the problem cause inside it is

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Models\weatherStatus;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class ApixuService
{
    public function query(string $apiKey, Collection $cities): Collection
    {
        $result = collect();
        $guzzleClient = new Client([ //create quzzle Client
            'base_uri' => 'http://api.weatherstack.com'
        ]);
        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $response = $guzzleClient->get('current', [
                'query' => [
                    'access_key' => $apiKey,
                    'query' => $city->name,
                ]
            ]);
            $response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true); //create json from $response
            $status = new weatherStatus(); //create weatherStatus object
            //adding prameters
            $status->city()->associate($city);
            $status->temp_celsius = $response['current']['temperature'];
            $status->status = $response['current']['weather_descriptions'];
            $status->last_update = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($response['location']['localtime_epoch']);
            $status->provider = 'weatherstack.com';
            //save prameters


            $status->save();

            $result->push($status);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saving some array in attribute. You need to use a ttpe caster on Eloquent. See laravel Eloquent docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can find some clarity in what you are trying to save, do the following:

```
$response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

dd($response);
```

`dd()` will dump all the data from the `$response` and exist the script.

One of the values you are trying to save is an array. The field you are trying to save accepts a `string` and not `array`.